# jinja2 - Display items without brackets/quotes

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm returning a list to my Flask View but I want to display it without the brackets or single quotes.

My HTML is formatted simply around a bootstrap dropdown

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Park Names
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      {% for park in parks_found %}
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ park }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Which outputs the drop down as shown - I would love to display it without the brackets/quotes -
Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like each `park` item is a list of one item and not a string. In other words, `parks_found` contains a list of lists and not a list of park names as strings.

## Solution

You can either make sure `parks_found` is a list of strings before passing, or you can grab the first item from it. Alternatively, if it's possible that each item inside `parks_found` actually contains a list, you add another loop for each `park` item.

#### View

```
def view():
    return render_template('index.html',
                           parks_found=[['Park A'], ['Park B']],
                           flat_parks_found=['Park A', 'Park B'])
```

#### Html

```
<h1>Original</h1>
{% for park in parks_found %}
<p>{{ park }}</p>
{% endfor %}

<h1>Grab first item</h1>
{% for park in parks_found %}
<p>{{ park[0] }}</p>
{% endfor %}

<h1>Flattaned list</h1>
{% for park in flat_parks_found %}
<p>{{ park }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

#### HTML Output

---

## Original

['Park A']

['Park B']

## Grab first item

Park A

Park B

## Flattaned list

Park A

Park B

---

Comment: Thanks! Such a simple mistake - "list of lists"